# Javascript HTML Table get first column's cell value based on another cell's onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I am making a PHP web application and fetching data from MySql into the HTML table below.

```
<table id = "table" width="500px" cellpadding=2 celspacing=5 border=2 >
 <tr>
   <th>Subject Code</th>
   <th>Subject Name</th>
   <th>Question Paper</th>
 </tr>
 <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)):?>
 <tr>
   <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Subject_Code'];?></td>
   <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Subject_Name'];?></td>
   <td align="center"><a href="javascript:showPaper()"><img border="0" alt="image" src="ProjectPictures/questionPaper.png" width="30" height="30"></a></td>
 </tr>
 <?php endwhile;?> 
</table>
```

Here is the output of the table

[image]

The third column consists of clickable image icons which loads question papers in an iFrame besides it.

I want that when this image is clicked, the cell value of the first column --> 'Subject code' for that particular row is obtained.

Here is the code:

```
function showPaper(){
   var v;
   //method1 not working
   for(var i=1;i<table.rows.length; i++){
      table.rows[i].onclick = function(){
        rIndex = this.rowsIndex;
        v=this.cells[0].innerHTML;
        alert(v);
      };
   }
  //method 2 not working
  v = $("#table tr.selected td:first").html(); 
  alert(v);            
  /*loc1 path rest of code
  document.getElementById('myiFrame').src = loc1*/;  
}
```

I require this subject code value as one of the variables in the pdf src path of the iFrame.

But nothing seems to be working, the value in 'v' variable is showing undefined.

How can I make this code work?

Comment: pass `Subject_Code` directly to the function.and then you can do whatever you want inside the function using this id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `onclick()` event to get value of `Subject_Code` .

Change

```
<td align="center"><a href="javascript:showPaper()"><img border="0" alt="image" src="ProjectPictures/questionPaper.png" width="30" height="30"></a></td>
```

With

```
<td align="center" id="<?php echo $row['Subject_Code'];?>" onclick="showPaper(this.id);"><img border="0" alt="image" src="ProjectPictures/questionPaper.png" width="30" height="30"></td>
```

And your `showPaper()` should be

```
<script>
    function showPaper(id)
    {
        alert(id);
        //Do something
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It worked! thank you so much Rahul Shrivastava. I am now able to obtain the subject code. Its a very good perspective to use td onclick to obtain an html table's cell value. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: @Simran  instead of adding `Subject_Code` in id  first and then using `this.id`, you can pass `Subject_Code` directly to the function.You can check my answer for reference